# Can I use variable in condition statement as value with where condition that test that value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[insertperoll] @name nvarchar(50) , @snum int , @gnum int
as

DECLARE @value nvarchar(10)  
SET @value = 's'+CONVERT(nvarchar(50),@snum)


DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @sqlText2 nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @sqlText3 nvarchar(1000);

declare @g nvarchar(50) = '''g1'''

SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ' + @value + N' FROM dbo.GrideBtable'
SET @sqlText2 = ' where Gnumber = '+@g --here is the problem it error invalid column name -- the          @g is value from the table condition
set @sqlText3 = @sqlText+@sqlText2
Exec (@sqlText3) -- here how can i save the result of the exec into varibale
declare @sal nvarchar(50) = @sqlText3

insert employ (name,Snumber,Gnumber,Salary) values(@name,@snum,@gnum,@sal)
```

QUESTION: How to put in condition variable gets value from the table when i exec it it think that the @g is column but its not its a value from the table to test it so i display one value after the exec the other QUESTION is how to save the result from the exec in variable and then use that value

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (9.0 RTM)

This will be a stored procedure

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is Gnumber an integer or string?

Comment: it is string nvarchar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do this using `sp_executesql` instead of `exec()` since this will allow you to use parameters, you can use an output parameter to get the value from the query:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @val = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@snum) + 
                            N' FROM dbo.GrideBtable WHERE Gnumber = @G1';
DECLARE @val INT; -- NOT SURE OF DATATYPE REQUIRED
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@G1 VARCHAR(20), @val INT OUT', 'G1', @val OUT;
```

Comment: how can i use the @val out to save it into variable ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would go through all the loops to insert into the table where you can have a simple insert query like ..

```
ALTER PROC dbo.[insertperoll] @name nvarchar(50) , @snum int , @gnum int
AS
insert employ (name, Snumber, Gnumber, Salary) 
select @name
    , @sum
    , @gnum
    , case when @snum = 1 then s1
         when @snum = 2 then s2
         when @snum = 3 then s3
         when @snum = 4 then s4
         end as Salary
    from dbo.GrideBtable
    where Gnumber = @gnum
```

Comment: If you look at the original proc again you'll see that there is no `salary`column in the source table. It's built up from concatenating `'s' + @snum`. Unless I'm completely misreading it.

Comment: @jpw .. Thanks! I did miss the info. I have edited my script to reflect this.

Comment: There is no need to dymanic SQL that I can see. This is much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: mate i need it because i need to pass the column name @value

Comment: @user3766910.. Your `@value` is derived from `@snum` which in turn is used to return a column value from GrideBtable. If @snum = 1 then you are getting the value from column `s1` in table `GrideBtable` and if @snum = 2 the column `s2` value is retrieved from `GrideBtable`. I guess it depends on how many columns you have in `GrideBtable`. The option is yours mate to use dynamic insert query or simple insert query

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to have the proc retrieve a salary value from a column determined from the parameter snum and then make an insert into employ using the values passed as parameters and the salary retrieved I think you could refactor your procedure to this:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[insertperoll] @name nvarchar(50) , @snum int , @gnum int AS

DECLARE @g NVARCHAR(50) = 'g1'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'INSERT employ (name,Snumber,Gnumber,Salary) '
SET @sql += N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@name, '''') 
SET @sql += N', ' + CAST(@snum AS NVARCHAR(50)) 
SET @sql += N', ' + CAST(@gnum AS NVARCHAR(50)) 
SET @sql += N', s' + CAST(@snum AS NVARCHAR(50))
SET @sql += N' FROM dbo.GrideBtable'
SET @sql += N' WHERE Gnumber = ' + QUOTENAME(@g, '''')

EXEC (@sql)
```

Of course you could add the @g variable to the procedure parameters instead of having it hard coded in the procedure and call it as:

```
EXEC insertperoll @name='john', @snum=10, @gnum=100, @g='g1'
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90dcd/1) (with some assumptions made about table structure)